# Why is my AWS DeepLens unable to connect to WiFi?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-deeplens

I am setting up my AWS DeepLens and all the steps have been successful until I try to connect to my home WiFi. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I created a hotspot on my phone to test against a different network and this connection was successful. Then, I switched back to my home WiFi and it connected successfully.

[This section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/deeplens/latest/dg/troubleshooting-device-registration.html#troubleshooting-device-wifi-connection) of the troubleshooting guide will also fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

We found that the AWS DeepLens only has one network adapter which it uses both for its own hotspot and connecting to the network. If you are connected to it via any other means (e.g. via a phone) it will throw a hissy and start dropping the connection, repeatedly and seemingly randomly.

When we connected a monitor directly we then found it was stuck on a viewable password prompt, hence why it was not connecting to our network.

Best method by far (and from our experience, only usable option) is to connect directly to the device so you can see what it is doing. To do this you need USB keyboard and mouse, and a mini-HDMI to HDMI cable to hook up a monitor. This will free up the network card to do only one thing.

When connecting please note that the default admin password on ours was "aws_cam". This does not seem to be noted anywhere in the documentation. This will change when you go through the setup process and sync it with your AWS account.

Answer (score 1):

Repeat the process by inserting a pin in the hole at the back of DeepLens. Wait for a few seconds, the wifi indicator (the middle light) would blink and then you can connect with Deeplens wireless network. Then you can open http://deeplens.config where you can configure your home wifi and complete the setup.